# Oauth error (twitter integration)

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth

Sorry if it could easy for you, but have 2 days that I trying to find a working twitter sample, every sample stop when try to request token, reading twitter forum, people says that could be internal system clock, I´ve set to my local date and time.

Using:

public static final String REQUEST_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token";

public static final String ACCESS_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token";

public static final String AUTHORIZE_URL = "http://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize";

Callback URL    http://www.google.com (inside twitter Oauth Settings, people says to not leave it blank)

I already checked both tokens, and set to read and write.

Comment: Try verifying the application key, secret and above mentioned urls with your twitter application.

Comment: I did it, it is obvious that I´ve checked! I am not a dumb, I just asked here because I´ve tried everything, so please give me a better answer and took off your vote down.

Comment: i think this problem with your internet connection see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twitter4j => AndroidRuntime(446): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken

Following error messages:

```
E/dalvikvm(374): Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated
W/dalvikvm(374): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Ltwitter4j/http/AccessToken;) in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;
D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: dead code 0x0012-002f in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;.isAuthenticated (Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;)Z
E/dalvikvm(374): Could not find class 'twitter4j.http.AccessToken', referenced from method com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.TwitterUtils.sendTweet
W/dalvikvm(374): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 67 (Ltwitter4j/http/AccessToken;) in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;
D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0010
D/dalvikvm(374): VFY: dead code 0x0012-002b in Lcom/ecs/android/sample/twitter/TwitterUtils;.sendTweet (Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;Ljava/lang/String;)V
D/AndroidRuntime(374): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(374): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(374): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.TwitterUtils.isAuthenticated(TwitterUtils.java:18)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.AndroidTwitterSample.updateLoginStatus(AndroidTwitterSample.java:72)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at com.ecs.android.sample.twitter.AndroidTwitterSample.onResume(AndroidTwitterSample.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1668)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime(374): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**To fix:** just have to change folder name from "lib" to "libs".

See: [Issue #2](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidTwitterSample/issues/2)

Answer (score 0):

add this permission in your manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

and follow this link

http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application

Comment: Yes, I already tried this sample and it is already with INTERNET permission. In this sample I got a error in line: AccessToken a = new AccessToken(token,secret);